# jQuery UI Nested droppable's event's don't get fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, drag-and-drop

I am trying to nest droppables and conditionally stop the propagation of the events. The problem is, I can't have the `greedy` property set because then the event never bubbles up the tree.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz6G6/4/

Comment: You can try to use `e.stopPropagation()` inside de drop function. Btw, I tried to change just the second greedy to true and the "Dropped on inner" was fired.

Comment: It doesn't do anything when `e.stopPropagation` is called. The inner is fired when greedy is on, but like I said then the event can't bubble up to the parent. The whole point was to conditionally allow the inner to bubble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. in order for the events to propagate properly, you have to bind to the element manually, you can't use the "drop" property of the configuration object.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz6G6/7/

Comment: @HowToPlease it was at the time this was written over a year ago. At a glance I don't see what could have changed

Comment: My problem was solved, I need to re bind the droppable function after a new parent was dropped :-D